# Creating shipping address object when order is posted to DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views

I currently have a form on my checkout page, when a user enters their shipping address and clicks proceed to payment it creates a new Order object by posting the cart details to my OrderViewSet.

I am wondering how I could integrate a ShippingAddressSerializer into the OrderViewSet. I would like it to retrieve all the fields as shown below once the form button is clicked.

**Current Serializers:**

```
class CreateOrderSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    cart_id = serializers.UUIDField()
    
    def validate_cart_id(self, cart_id):
        if not Cart.objects.filter(pk=cart_id).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'No cart with the given ID was found.')
        if CartItem.objects.filter(cart_id=cart_id).count() == 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('The cart is empty.')
        return cart_id

    def save(self, **kwargs):

        with transaction.atomic():
            cart_id = self.validated_data['cart_id']

            customer = Customer.objects.get(user_id=self.context['user_id'])
            order = Order.objects.create(customer=customer)

            cart_items = CartItem.objects \
                                    .select_related('product') \
                                    .filter(cart_id=cart_id)
            order_items = [
                OrderItem( 
                    order=order,
                    product=item.product,
                    unit_price=item.product.price,
                    quantity=item.quantity,
                )  for item in cart_items
            ]

            OrderItem.objects.bulk_create(order_items)

            Cart.objects.filter(pk=cart_id).delete()

            order_created.send_robust(self.__class__, order=order)

            return order
    

class ShippingAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ShippingAddress
        fields = ['customer', 'order', 'house', 'street', 'city', 'postcode']
```

**OrderViewSet:**

```
class OrderViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'delete', 'head', 'options']

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in ['PATCH', 'DELETE']:
            return [IsAdminUser()]
        return [IsAuthenticated()]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = CreateOrderSerializer(
            data=request.data,
      

  context={'user_id': self.request.user.id}
        )
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    order = serializer.save()
    serializer = OrderSerializer(order)
    return Response(serializer.data)


def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        return CreateOrderSerializer
    elif self.request.method == 'PATCH':
        return UpdateOrderSerializer
    return OrderSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    if user.is_staff:
        return Order.objects.all()
    customer_id = Customer.objects.only('id').get(user_id=user.id)
    return Order.objects.filter(customer_id=customer_id)
```